# Force YAML values to be strings

Tags: python, yaml

Look at this code, under Python 2.7:

```
>>> import yaml
>>> yaml.load('string: 01')
{'string': 1}
>>> :(
```

Is it possible to obtain the string `01` without modifying the yaml file? I didn't find anything in the docs.

Comment: I don't think it is possible. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Because it is the name of a file (`01.in`) in my directory.

Comment: But how did you end up with that yaml file then?

Comment: I'm making a new version of an app, and the previous one didn't use a YAML library: they just parsed the YAML file by hand.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try:

```
>> import yaml
>> yaml.load('string: 01', Loader=yaml.loader.BaseLoader)
{u'string': u'01'}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was seeking for exactly the opposite effect: Numbers where being converted to stings, but numbers where wanted. I was using accidentally the BaseLoader (Dame copy-paste!).

The **LOADER** is the answer, as already stated by @Konrad Hałas.

Force Strings:

```
yaml.load('string: 01', Loader=yaml.loader.BaseLoader)
```

Force Number: (Default)

```
yaml.load('string: 01', Loader=yaml.loader.SafeLoader)
```

Link about *Deprecation* and detail:

https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/wiki/PyYAML-yaml.load(input)-Deprecation