# YAML file update and delete using python?

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I have a YAML file and it looks like below

```
test:
 - exam.com
 - exam1.com
 - exam2.com
test2:
 - examp.com
 - examp1.com
 - examp2.com
```

I like to manage this file using python. 
Task is, I like to add an entry under "test2" and delete entry from "test".

Comment: load the data into a python dictionary using the yaml library.. add / delete as you would from a regular python dict / list. write the original file

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28557626/how-to-update-yaml-file-using-python

Answer (score 1):

You first have to load the data, which will give you a top-level dict (in a variable called `data` in the following example), the values for the keys will be lists. On those lists you can do the `del` resp. `insert()` (or `append()`)

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
test:
 - exam.com
 - exam1.com
 - exam2.com
test2:
 - examp.com
 - examp1.com  # want to insert after this
 - examp2.com
"""

data = ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load(yaml_str)
del data['test'][1]
data['test2'].insert(2, 'examp1.5')
ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(data, sys.stdout, block_seq_indent=1)
```

gives:

```
test:
 - exam.com
 - exam2.com
test2:
 - examp.com
 - examp1.com  # want to insert after this
 - examp1.5
 - examp2.com
```

The `block_seq_indent=1` is necessary as by default `ruamel.yaml` will left align a sequence value with the key.¹

If you want to get rid of the comment in the output you can do:

```
data['test2']._yaml_comment = None
```

---

¹ <sub>This was done using [ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml) a YAML 1.2 parser, of which I am the author.</sub>