# python use Pyyaml and keep format

Tags: python, yaml

Here is a config file, I use PyYAML to change some value from it and then I write some config, but it will change my format, it confuses me.

```
 $ results.yaml 
 nas:
     mount_dir: '/nvr'
     mount_dirs: ['/mount/data0', '/mount/data1', '/mount/data2']

# yaml.py

import yaml.py

conf = open("results.conf", "r")
results = yaml.load(conf)
conf.close()

result['nas']['mount_dirs'][0]= "haha"

with open('/home/zonion/speedio/speedio.conf', 'w') as conf:
    yaml.dump(speedio, conf, default_flow_style=False)

conf.close()
```

but it change my format,what should I do?

```
# cat results.conf
nas:
  mount_dir: /nvr
  mount_dirs:
  - haha
  - /mount/data1
  - /mount/data2
```

Comment: Can we take it your extra space before `nas` (and the following lines) is because of inappropriate formatting here on [so], and that your actual indent is four spaces? BTW, if you `import yaml.py` you will get an `ImportError`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use [`ruamel.yaml`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml/) ¹, you can relatively easily achieve this, by combining [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29604834/1307905) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35406862/1307905) answer here on StackOverlow.

By default `ruamel.yaml` normalizes to an indent of 2, and drops superfluous quotes. As you don't seem to want that, you have to either explicitly set the indent, or have `ruamel.yaml` analyse the input, and tell it to preserve quotes:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml
import ruamel.yaml.util

yaml_str = """\
nas:
    mount_dir: '/nvr'
    mount_dirs: ['/mount/data0', '/mount/data1', '/mount/data2']
"""

result, indent, block_seq_indent = ruamel.yaml.util.load_yaml_guess_indent(
    yaml_str, preserve_quotes=True)
result['nas']['mount_dirs'][0] = "haha"
ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(result, sys.stdout, indent=indent,
                            block_seq_indent=block_seq_indent)
```

instead of the `load_yaml_guess_indent()` invocation you can do:

```
result = ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load(yaml_str, preserve_quotes=True)
indent = 4
block_sequence_indent = None
```

If you want `haha` to be (single) quoted in the output make it a `SingleQuotedScalarString`:

```
result['nas']['mount_dirs'][0] = \
       ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.SingleQuotedScalarString("haha")
```

with that the output will be:

```
nas:
    mount_dir: '/nvr'
    mount_dirs: ['haha', '/mount/data1', '/mount/data2']
```

(given that your short example input has no block style sequences, the `block_sequence_indent` cannot be determined and will be None)

---

When using the newer API you have control over the indent of the mapping and sequences seperately:

```
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.indent(mapping=4, sequence=6, offset=3)  # not that that looks nice
data = yaml.load(some_stream)
yaml.dump(data, some_stream)
```

This will make your YAML formatted consistently if it wasn't so to begin with, and make no further changes after the first round-trip.

---

¹ <sub>Disclaimer: I am the author of that package.</sub>

Comment: what version of ruamel is this ? becuase its not working on my machine in office which is `0.10.12`

Comment: @ChangZhao "is this" is a bit unspecific, but if you mean the new API, that was introduced with 0.15.1 in June 2017. I am not sure why you are using 0.10.12, that was from 2015 IIRC and there have been way over 100 releases of `ruamel.yaml`  since then.

Comment: well after importing ruamel  when I type ruamel in python shell, I get `<module 'ruamel' (built-in)>` so ruamel comes as a builtin ? and it seems to be ruamel never got installed or updated since then ?

Comment: You should just do a `pip install -U ruamel.yaml`

Answer (score 6):

`ruamel.yaml` unfortunately **does not** completely preserve original format, quoting its [docs](https://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html):

> Although individual indentation of lines is not preserved, you can
>   specify separate indentation levels for mappings and sequences
>   (counting for sequences does not include the dash for a sequence
>   element) and specific offset of block sequence dashes within that
>   indentation.

I do not know any Python library that does that.

When I need to change a YAML file without touching its format I reluctantly use regexp (reluctantly as it's almost as bad as [parsing XHTML with it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)).

Please feel free to suggest a better solution if you know any, I would gladly learn about it!

Comment: Please add a comment explaining why I am wrong in a harmful way if you are downvoting me.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[ruamel](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml) implements a round-trip loader and dumper, try:

```
import ruamel.yaml
conf = open("results.conf", "r")
results = ruamel.yaml.load(conf, ruamel.yaml.RoundTripLoader)
conf.close()
results['nas']['mount_dirs'][0] = "haha"
with open('/home/zonion/speedio/speedio.conf', 'w') as conf:
  ruamel.yaml.dump(results, conf, ruamel.yaml.RoundTripDumper)
```

Comment: thank you for you help, but it make my single quotes disappear！！！
Like ： [haha,  /mount/data1,  /mount/data2]，
By the way,  the  Indentation is not right too.

Comment: Well then ruamel is not as round-tripping as it advertizes to be. You can customize its output by adding parameters to dump; in your case, `indent=4, default_style="'"` might help (but might also result in *all* scalars to be quoted). Note that round-tripping is nothing YAML is designed to do, and trying to do it violates the YAML spec. The real answer is probably „if you want round-tripping, YAML is not the right tool to use“.

Answer (score 0):

Try to load it first and the dump like that:

```
import ruamel.yaml
yaml_str = f"""\
    nas:
        mount_dir: '/nvr'
        mount_dirs: ['/mount/data0', '/mount/data1', '/mount/data2']"""
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)

with open("test.yaml", 'w') as outfile:
    yaml.dump(data, outfile)
outfile.close()
```