# How can I edit a yaml file while preserving the format using a python script?

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I want to read and write to several yaml files without changing the entire format of the file. When I use `yaml.load` and `yaml.dump` the format is entirely changed, resulting in many changed lines.

I only want to insert a key into several dictionaries that are missing the key. I also looked into using [ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml/) but it does not preserve format according to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54278583/4044470

Comment: Look for a pretty print python library for yaml.

Comment: That answer doesn't say ruamel.yaml does not preserve format. It says it does not completely preserve the original format. And that is not the accepted answer for the question. You can use ruamel.yaml to analyse your indentation, and it will make it consistent over the full YAML document. So if your document is already consistent within itself, there is more than a good chance that round-tripping does keep things as they are.