# Dump a yaml file to disk using ruamel

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I'm having difficulty modifying a saved YAML file. I want to load it, add a property to the dict, and re-save it. This is what I've done... (Python 3.9.7)

```
# my_file.yaml

- id: 001
  name: Steve
  likes:
    - soccer
    - steak
- id: 002
  name: Mary
  likes:
    - tennis
    - ice cream
```

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

with open("my_file.yaml") as file:
  yaml = YAML()
  l = yaml.load(file)
```

```
l[0]["address"] = "123 Street"
with open("my_file_new.yaml", 'w') as f:
  yaml.dump(l, f)
```

output too long to include, but it is definitely not what I expected.

How do I get the original file with just one extra row added?

Comment: Potential duplicate ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28557626/how-to-update-yaml-file-using-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use a string as the first argument to `open()`, and you might not
be doing that
in the second invocation, as
it is unclear from your code where your variable `my_new_file` is declared, and what it has an
attribute `.yaml`.

Instead provide a string as first argument to `open()`, and while you are at it,
always open YAML documents as binary (`'rb'` resp. `'wb'`),
or (preferably) use a `pathlib.Path()`:

```
import pathlib
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
old_path = pathlib.Path('my_file.yaml')
new_path = pathlib.Path('my_file_new.yaml')

yaml = YAML()
with open('my_file.yaml') as file:
  l = yaml.load(file)
# replace the previous two lines with: l = yaml.load(l, old_path)

l[0]['address'] = '123 Street'
with open('my_file_new.yaml', 'wb') as f:
  yaml.dump(l, f)
# replace the previous two lines with: yaml.dump(l, new_path)

print(new_path.read_text())
```

which gives:

```
# my_file.yaml

- id: 001
  name: Steve
  likes:
  - soccer
  - steak
  address: 123 Street
- id: 002
  name: Mary
  likes:
  - tennis
  - ice cream
```

Comment: I see what I did: `yaml = YAML()` wasn't available to the write method. Thanks!

Comment: and the destination file was supposed to be a string. I have corrected it.